# Where is Exchange Online Multipart message limit set?

Tags: exchange

A user reported that one of their suppliers started getting NDRs when sending a airline tickets via email.  The NDR says:

```
Remote Server returned: '550 Too many MIME parts: 178 > 100'
```

When looking this up I found that [the default Multipart message limit is 250](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#message-limits), not 100 so it looks like this has been changed at some point to 100.  I recently enabled the [Microsoft Defender Standard preset security policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/preset-security-policies?view=o365-worldwide) so I am wondering if this made that change, or it was something else.

I can't find any individual setting in Anti-spam, Anti-phishing or Anti-malware policies that appears to relate to Multipart message limit or MIME parts, and all the suggestions relating to this kind of NDR tells the sender to ask the recipient to change the limit - with no guidance for a recipient admin on how to actually do that!

The messages don't have large attachments nor are they sent to multiple recipients, so I am not sure why they are splitting into more than 100 parts - but 100 parts seems to be below the default anyway...

I'd like to allow this kind of message to get through but don't really want to turn off all the security in order to do so.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Look through the message tracking log if you can find any more info. Because MIME is not multipart `Get-MessageTrace -RecipientAddress <user’s address> -StartDate 11/07/2017 -EndDate 11/14/2017 -Status Failed | Get-MessageTraceDetail`. (for example)

Comment: Message trace doesn't show _any_ failed messages to this recipient in the last two days. If the mail server rejects a message at the point when the sending mail server hands it over, does this definitely end up in a Message Trace?

Comment: You can do a trace up to 90 days with Start-HistoricalSearch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/start-historicalsearch?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Yes a detailed report can even include a link to the delivery status notification report https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/monitoring/trace-an-email-message/message-trace-modern-eac